# Server client communication using Javaservlets and JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to understand the aspects to build dynamic web application by referring many resources. I am facing issue while I am trying to communicate and pass the parameter from AJAX to java servlets and to JSP.
Please find the code below:

```
**HTML Code**:
<button onclick="viewcart()">ViewMyCart</button>
<script>
function viewcart(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'./ShowCart',
});
}
</script>

**Servlet (ShowCart):**
try {
        System.out.println("In ShowCart code");
        LoginDB log=new LoginDB();
        Connection con=log.connect();

        String SQL="select * from bookname";
        PreparedStatement prep=con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs=prep.executeQuery(SQL);
        ArrayList<String> bookname=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            bookname.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
       System.out.println("bookname is"+bookname);
       request.setAttribute("MyBookNames", bookname);
       request.getRequestDispatcher("Display.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

**Display.JSP:**
<h1> Your cart </h1>
<%
ArrayList<String> booknames_list=    (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("MyBookNames");
System.out.println("In JSP class Display");
System.out.println(booknames_list);

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Values are actually in booknames_list . But I wanted to display the values in a separate page. Can you all please guide me in achieving the same?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to display values in a different page, then you don't use ajax. You submit the form normally.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. I am actually studying and got to know about form and servlet connection. But, if you could please tell me is there a way to perform this kind of action without using forms?

Comment: yes, you can just submit a form via javascript. I can give you an example answer if you want. Are you using jquery in your project?

Comment: I am actually looking to do this in AJAX itself for learning purpose.

Comment: AJAX is for asynchronous processing. Which means you do don't need to refresh the page or change page.